# idHTTP Post response html cortado

Tags: delphi, post

Buenas.

Estou fazendo um Post via idHTTP onde o resultado vem em um `StringStream`.

O problema que este resultado está vindo pela metade. No caso, cortando o html de resposta.

Existe um jeito de bufferizar esta Post?

Obs.: Utilizo DelphiXE7.

```
  var
    fHTTP: THTTP;//Classe que utilizo para alimentar o idHTTP
    slParam: TStringList;
  begin
    fHTTP := THTTP.Create;
    slParam := TStringList.Create;
    try
      slParam.Add('modo=C');
      slParam.Add('NumeroRENACH=');
      slParam.Add('txtDocPrincipal=');
      slParam.Add('oculto=');
      slParam.Add('txtCodigo='+ fCaptcha);
      slParam.Add('Submit=Consultar');

      fHTTP.pLimpaParams;
      fHTTP.Params.Host := 'consultas.detrannet.sc.gov.br';
      fHTTP.Params.Connection := 'keep-alive';
      fHTTP.Params.ContentLength := Length(slParam.Text);
      fHTTP.Params.CacheControl := 'max-age=0';
      fHTTP.Params.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36';
      fHTTP.Params.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      fHTTP.Params.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
      fHTTP.Params.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
      fHTTP.Params.AcceptLanguage := 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4';
      fHTTP.Params.CustomHeaders.Values['Cookie'] := ACookie;
      fHTTP.Params.CustomHeaders.Values['Upgrade-Insecure-Requests'] := '1';

      fHTTP.Params.ProtocolVersion := 1;

      fHTTP.Post('http://consultas.detrannet.sc.gov.br'+RemotePath,slParam);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(fHTTP);
    FreeAndNil(slParam);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema está aqui. 
`fHTTP.Params.ContentLength := Length(slParam.Text);` 
O length do seu slParam deve ser bem pequeno, faz um teste, coloca 10000 no ContentLength, provavelmente é isso. 
O contentlength que dita qual o tamanho da resposta que você vai receber.

Se não funcionar, verifica se o componente tem o atributo response, provavelmente no response também vai ter o ContentLength, ai você seta ele para um numero grande para efetuar esse teste. 
Se tiver o atributo response acredito que ficaria assim...

```
fHTTP.Response.ContentLength := 10000
```

Comment: Valeu pela resposta.
Então, o PostData é só aquilo no stringlist.
Descobri que o problema não estava no idHTTP mas em uma função que salva pra arquivo onde não tinha feito o ajuste de Unicode pois copiei do projeto do Delphi 7.